# How can I show the latest Tweets on a particular subject in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter

I want to add a section to a web page that will contain a scrolling list of the latest Tweets on a particular subject. How can this be accomplished?

If it is always the same subject, would it be as easy as embedding a web page within a web page with the URL:

http://topsy.com/s?q=%23marktwain

(replacing "marktwain" with whatever the subject is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues you'll face is the need to use OAuth on all your queries, which is required by Twitter API v1.1. Twitter has deprecated v1.0 of the API and will start doing blackouts before shutting it down next month. I don't see any Web page widgets on Twitter's Web page to do this either.

If you embedded this in a Web page, you would need a JavaScript OAuth library, which also means that your credentials must be in your Web page - an insecure approach.

Silverlight is a possibility, but Microsoft's focus on HTML/JavaScript leaves it's future in a questionable state. Besides, someone could also decompile the component and get your credentials, which is also not secure.

This leaves a server-side solution as the best possibility. You could handle this via pull or push. SignalR would be a good approach for push, but the tradeoff is that you need a continuously running process for immediate updates. If you run your own server, you could run a process via Windows Service that either does periodic Search queries, or uses a Filter Stream and uses SignalR to push results to the page. In the pull approach, your page can run a timer with an Ajax query back to the server, collecting new tweets and displaying them on the page. These are just a couple ideas, but provided to give you an idea of how you might approach the problem.

Twitter has a list of [Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) you can use. I wrote [LINQ to Twitter](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/), which also supports Twitter API v1.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tweetsharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) to leverage the twitter api

Answer (score 2):

you can create an [embedded timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) or you could try out [live tweet](https://github.com/sergiomartino/jQuery-LiveTweet) - a jquery plugin

Comment: I'd go with this one. The live tweet will keep refreshing client-side

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something recently. Hope this helps. https://devtasks.blogspot.com/2013/06/console-app-that-displays-twitter-feed.html

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using LinqToTwitter;
using System.Threading;

namespace Linq2Twitter
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Controls the flow of the program.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The args.</param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This is a super simple example that
            // retrieves the latest tweets of a given 
            // twitter user.

            // SECTION A: Initialise local variables
            Console.WriteLine("SECTION A: Initialise local variables");

            // Access token goes here .. (Please generate your own)
            const string accessToken = "Access token goes here .. (Please generate your own)";
            // Access token secret goes here .. (Please generate your own)
            const string accessTokenSecret = "Access token secret goes here .. (Please generate your own)";

            // Api key goes here .. (Please generate your own)
            const string consumerKey = "Api key goes here .. (Please generate your own)";
            // Api secret goes here .. (Please generate your own)
            const string consumerSecret = "Api secret goes here .. (Please generate your own)";

            // The twitter account name goes here
            const string twitterAccountToDisplay = "roeburg"; 


            // SECTION B: Setup Single User Authorisation
            Console.WriteLine("SECTION B: Setup Single User Authorisation");
            var authorizer = new SingleUserAuthorizer
            {
                CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
                {
                    ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
                    ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
                    OAuthToken = accessToken,
                    OAuthTokenSecret = accessTokenSecret
                }
            };

            // SECTION C: Generate the Twitter Context
            Console.WriteLine("SECTION C: Generate the Twitter Context");
            var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(authorizer);

            // SECTION D: Get Tweets for user
            Console.WriteLine("SECTION D: Get Tweets for user");
            var statusTweets = from tweet in twitterContext.Status
                               where tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
                                       tweet.ScreenName == twitterAccountToDisplay &&
                                       tweet.IncludeContributorDetails == true &&
                                       tweet.Count == 10 &&
                                       tweet.IncludeEntities == true
                               select tweet;

            // SECTION E: Print Tweets
            Console.WriteLine("SECTION E: Print Tweets");
            PrintTweets(statusTweets);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Prints the tweets.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="statusTweets">The status tweets.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.NotImplementedException"></exception>
        private static void PrintTweets(IQueryable<Status> statusTweets)
        {
            foreach (var statusTweet in statusTweets)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\n\nTweet From [{0}] at [{1}]: \n-{2}",
                    statusTweet.ScreenName,
                    statusTweet.CreatedAt,
                    statusTweet.Text));
            
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```